# How can i make work SSL for Meteor on deferent port?

Tags: ssl, meteor, nginx

In mup.json i add:

```
"ssl": {
    "certificate": "/bundle.crt",
    "key": "/private.key",
    "port": 444
}
```

How can i install ssl on deferent from 443 port (443 already busy with plesk panel), and make it work? 
I guess also i have to add some config in nginx?